# How to configure more IPv6 addresses sooner at boot init time?

Tags: systemd, ipv6, init

I have a full /64 of IPv6 addresses allocated to my VPS running Ubuntu Xenial Xerus Server Edition 16.04.4 LTS recently upgraded. I put my configuration of 15 IPv6 addresses (:1 .. :f) in /etc/network/interfaces but only the first two would be started up at boot time.  So I put `ip addr add eth0 ${addr}` commands (in a loop to do one command per address) in /etc/rc.local and this works to get the IP addresses enabled.

The problem is this happens after all the server software is started and additional IPv6 addresses are not yet configured when the server software is started.  If I manually restart the service, it sees all the addresses and opens all the listen sockets it needs.

What I would like to know how to do is set up my additional addresses earlier in the boot init steps so the server software gets them all when they are started.

Below is a copy of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file with obscured network numbers.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
        address 127.0.0.1
        netmask 255.0.0.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 198.51.100.207
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 198.51.100.255
        network 198.51.100.0
gateway 198.51.100.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:db8:f00f:5775::1/48
netmask 48
gateway 2001:db8:f00f::1

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:db8:f00f:5775::2/48
netmask 48
gateway 2001:db8:f00f::1

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:db8:f00f:5775::3/48
netmask 48
gateway 2001:db8:f00f::1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 198.51.100.206
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 198.51.100.255
network 198.51.100.0
```

This file now has only 3 IPv6 addresses and only 2 of the work.  Address :3 is not set up by this file for some unknown reason.  If I could get all addresses to work here, I believe this work have them set up early enough to be used.

Below is a copy of my `/etc/rc.local` file with obscured network numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in 2001:db8:f00f:5775::{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}/48; do
   ip addr add dev eth0 "${n}"
done
```

Does anyone know how to get all 15 (:1 .. :f) IPv6 addresses configured early enough for starting software to see them all?  IPv4 is working OK, perhaps because it uses interface aliases for extra addresses.

Comment: Does your server software really need to bind to specific IPv6 addresses? Usually you would just bind to IN6ADDR_ANY (i.e. `[::]`) and the OS will send all relevant traffic to the server.

Comment: the server software itself needs to bind to these addresses because other things connect there.  if the server software did not listen there then they could not be connected to.